# SPARQL: Number of Statements in each Named Graph

Tags: sparql, rdf, allegrograph, named-graphs

The following query returns the number of statements in a repository:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?count) 
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o
}
```

Is there a way to return the number of statements for each Named Graph?

This following query does not work, only an example:

```
SELECT ?graphName ?count 
WHERE {
  GRAPH ?graphName { 
    ?s ?p ?o. 
    BIND(COUNT(?s ?p ?o.) AS ?count)
  }
}
```

- I realize that `COUNT` can't be in the `WHERE`, and it can't take variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `GROUP BY` clause to your query --

```
SELECT ?graphName
       ( COUNT ( * ) AS ?count )
WHERE
  {
    GRAPH ?graphName
      {
        ?s ?p ?o
      }
  }
GROUP BY ?graphName
```

See [the query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=SELECT%20%3FgraphName%20%28COUNT%28*%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20GRAPH%20%3FgraphName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3FgraphName&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) and its [live results on DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%20%3FgraphName%20%28COUNT%28*%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20GRAPH%20%3FgraphName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3FgraphName&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)